# Spring AOP Exception handling Advice not executed if catch block is there

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

Im am using Spring AOP to log exceptions in my class. It is supposed to log all exceptions thrown in every method of the class.

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* *.*(..))", throwing = "e")
protected void method(JoinPoint joinPoint,Exception e) throws Throwable {
```

However, if the method has a try catch block which catches the exception, advice is not triggered. If i remove the try catch block and add throws clause in method definition then advice is called. Is this how AOP is supposed to work coz it makes no sense? I just want a generic exception handling code for all exceptions at one place instead of in every method.

Comment: possible related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132822/execution-vs-call-join-point

Comment: @VladBochenin, the other question you linked to is completely unrelated to this one.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is how it is supposed to work. The term "after throwing" already says when the advice kicks in: after the target method has been throwing an exception. Your method catches and never throws the exception you want to intercept, though. So what can you do?

- You either have to intercept it one or more levels up the call chain or
- you upgrade from Spring AOP to AspectJ and use the `handler()` pointcut in order to intercept the `catch` block in your method as described in the [AspectJ manual](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/language-joinPoints.html). You can also find sample code for `handler()` in [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42093318/1082681). How to activate full AspectJ with LTW is described in the [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj).

As a side note, I am wondering why you are trying to intercept a (hopefully properly) handled exception in the first place. Where is your sample code? What is your use case?

Comment: Thanks @kriegaex  , i thought spring AOP would be easier to implement than full AspectJ and more relevant as im working on a web application. My use case is that i want to avoid boiler plate logging code. I want to log method entry and exit and exceptions at one place for multiple classes and methods. In exceptions i want to log method name , exception, arguments.

Comment: Method entry exit advices are working fine for my DAO but i dont know how to implement for my servlets as its not a spring application and spring AOP only works for spring injected beans. Exception advices are not working as intended as i cannot throw uncaught exceptions from DAO to servlets. I need to advices to log exceptions in both DAO and servlets.

Comment: Well, my explanation already answers those questions: Use AspectJ instead of spring AOP. AspectJ _can_ be used from withing Spring, but otherwise is completely unrelated and stand-alone, it works with any Java (or other JVM language) application if configured correctly. So I would appreciate you accepting my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you handle the exception in the method using a try catch, then the method does not throw that exception.
AOP is only concerned with the input and output of the method and treats it like a black box, It's not concerned with what goes on inside the method.

Maybe you can move your try catch to the calling method instead.